# Simple assembly program arithmetic error

Tags: nasm

I tried to write a program that adds the digits of a 16-bit number "broj" and stores the result in a location named "rez".

Here's my code:

```
SECTION .data

broj DW 25326

SECTION .bss

rez RESW 1

SECTION .text
global _start
_start:

MOV CX, 10
MOV AX,[broj]
skok: 
DIV CX --> result in AX, remainder in DX
ADD [rez],DX
MOV BX,AX -->move the result of the last division
JNZ skok

MOV EAX,1
MOV EBX,0
int 80h
```

This produced an "arithmetic error", however, my assembly-debugging skills are more than limited.
I used kdbg under Mint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DIV CX` will divide the 32-bit value in `DX:AX` by `CX`. So you need to clear `DX` before the `DIV` (e.g. `XOR DX,DX`) to avoid getting a quotient that's larger than 16 bits.

Comment: I should've read the instruction set more carefully! :) Thank you!